# Baffled by -match and -notmatch RegEx results in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have some code that is designed to return a PSDriveInfo object for each disk drive that is not in a list of drive letters. I can get the inverse and can code round it but would really like to understand where I am going wrong. My server has 7 hard drives (C, D, E, H, I, L, W) my code is designed to return a PSDriveInfo object for all but drives E and H.

I have tried various comparison operators, `-ne`, `.ToString().Trim().Equals()` and `-match`. My code is currently based on the RegEx `-match` operator. If I use `-match` I get the inverse of what I want but if I use `-notmatch` I get every drive and I am baffled why this does not work. In the code window I show first what works and gives me the inverse of what I want then the code that confuses me as to why it does not work using the `-notmatch` operator.

```
Clear-Host
$exclude = "E,H"

"This gives me the inverse of what I want:"
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {
    $_.DriveType -eq 3
} | ForEach-Object {
    Get-PSDrive $_.DeviceId[0]
} | Where-Object {
    $driveName = $_.Name
    $exclude -split "," | ForEach-Object {
        if ($driveName -match $_) { return $true }
    }
} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name
}

"Why does this not work:"
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object {
    $_.DriveType -eq 3
} | ForEach-Object {
    Get-PSDrive $_.DeviceId[0]
} | Where-Object {
    $driveName = $_.Name
    $exclude -split "," | ForEach-Object {
        if ($driveName -notmatch $_) { return $true }
    }
} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name
}
```

The results of the code sample on my server:

This gives me the inverse of what I want using `-match`:

```
E
H
```

Why does `-notmatch` not work?

```
C
D
E
H
I
L
W
```

Comment: when you do `ForEach-Object{if( $driveName -notmatch $_ ){ return $true }}` _inside the `Where-Object` block_, you end up returning multiple `$true` values, which is why you seem to get everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `-notmatch` attempt, you are checking every drive of type 3 against every item in the exclude split within the last `Where-Object`. So you will always get at least one `$true` evaluation. So that means the `where-object` condition will always evaluate to `$true`.

Here is a trivial, albeit still convoluted, example of what is happening:

```
# Example 1
@(1,2,3,4) | where-object { $num = $_; $true,$false,$true |% {if ($_) {$num}}}
1
2
3
4

#Example 2:
@(1,2,3,4) | where-object { $num = $_; $false,$false,$false |% {if ($_) {$num}}}
```

Example 1 above always eventually evaluates to `$true` allowing for the current array object to be output. Example 2 never pipes a `$true` into the `if` statement, so it returns nothing. The only way your `-notmatch` code works is if nothing ever matches, and honestly I have no idea when that would happen.

I have taken your code and modified it to show you what is happening. If you run this, you will see that every drive returns at least one `True`.

```
$exclude = "E,H"

Get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk | 
    Where-Object { 
        $_.drivetype -eq 3 
    } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-PSDrive $_.deviceid[0] 
    } | 
    foreach-Object { 
        $driveName = $_.Name
        $exclude -split "," | 
        ForEach-Object{ 
            "Testing Drive $driveName -notmatch $_"
            if( $driveName -notmatch $_ ){ $true } 
            else {$false}
        }
    }
```

**Testing with Code Above:**

```
Testing Drive H -notmatch E
True
Testing Drive H -notmatch H
False
Testing Drive O -notmatch E
True
Testing Drive O -notmatch H
True
Testing Drive T -notmatch E
True
Testing Drive T -notmatch H
True
```

An easier way to solve this problem is to make use of the `-notin` operator.

```
$exclude = "E:","H:"

Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | 
    Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and $_.DeviceId -notin $exclude}
```

In the code above, `$exclude` is already an array and each value includes the `:` to make the code simpler. If you do not want to include the `:` in the variable, you can concatenate it in the next line like below:

```
$exclude = "E","H" | Foreach-Object {"{0}:" -f $_}

Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | 
    Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and $_.DeviceId -notin $exclude}
```

Answer (score 2):

your logic is ... convoluted, fragile, and doesn't properly account for how `-match` and `-notmatch` work against a collection. a more logical method is to use the `-in` or `-notin` collection operators.

```
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$ExcludedDriveList = 'e', 'h'

$DriveLetterList = @(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDisk |
    Where-Object {
        $_.DriveType -eq 3 -and
        $_.DeviceID.Trim(':') -notin $ExcludedDriveList
        }
    ).DeviceID.Trim(':')

$DriveLetterList
```

output ...

```
C
D
F
G
Z
```

that is only the HD/SSD items, i have two dvd-r drives, and a card reader that are not listed. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `"E", "H" -NotMatch "E"` is going to return "H" - see [Microsoft Docs on Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6). What you want in this case is simply to negate your `if` statement:

```bsh
...
if(!( $driveName -match $_ )) { return $true } # or if (-not ($driveName -match $_ ))
...
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me but I have tried both ways you describe with the same results as the original code and so still remain baffled! I also tried:    if (-not ($driveName.ToString().Trim() -match $_.Trim() )) { return $true }